# Pass inner class object as an argument to apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have following apex class as an example. I am writing unit test case for apex class and passing inner class object ref as an argument. When I try to save my test class it is giving me compilation error.
'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: TestInner.InnerA].testInnerMethod(TestInner.InnerA)'

Apex Class:

```
global class TestInner {
    global TestInner(){

    }
    global Class InnerA {
        global String a {get;set;}
        global String b {get;set;}
    }

    global List<String> testInnerMethod(InnerA innerFields){
        List<String> listOfString = new List<String>();
        String a = innerFields.a;
        String b = innerFields.b;
        listOfString.add(a);
        listOfString.add(b);
        return listOfString;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class UnitTestInner {
    public UnitTestInner(){

    }
    public static testMethod void testInnerClassRef(){        
        TestInner.InnerA testIn = new TestInner.InnerA();
        testIn.a = 'XYZ';
        testIn.b = 'POR';
        testIn.testInnerMethod(testIn); //Compilation error on this line
    }
}
```

What would be the approach to pass inner class as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `testInnerMethod` is defined in the nested `TestInner` class not the `TestInner.InnerA` class so this should work:

```
public static testMethod void testInnerClassRef(){        
    TestInner.InnerA innerA = new TestInner.InnerA();
    innerA.a = 'XYZ';
    innerA.b = 'POR';
    TestInner testInner = new TestInner();
    testInner.testInnerMethod(innerA);
}
```

Comment: Actually I screwed up! I shouldn't have posted this question. Though your answer is correct. I will mark it best answer.